# how do I control duty cycle of a MOSFET using PI controller

Tags: battery-charging, dc-dc-converter, control, pid-controller, duty-cycle

I have designed a buck boost converter, how can I use a PI controller which will automatically change the duty cycle of the mosfet as per my desired output voltage or current?
I have been fidgeting with the PID controller in simulink and have found a way to get my desired load current.I have used a signal generator to produce a square wave which is compared with the actual load current(which is negative and I'm using a negative feedback so it becomes positive, what?) and a Proportional controller of gain=5,I=D=0, the output of which is given to gate. I came to the conclusion that the load current is always equal to the amplitude of the square wave so can we can control it by changing amplitude of the square wave. Is this method credible? Honestly I don't really understand what's going on. Please take a look at the second picture

[image: Buck Boost revised]

[image: Converter Control]

Comment: You wanting it to work in simulink or for a real circuit? (If for a real, analogue or digital control)

Comment: Well the ultimate goal is to make it work for a real circuit but for now I wanna understand it through simulink

Comment: In simulink there's a block used for that. What you ussually want to do is make your pi give you an output from 0 to 1, corresponding to 0% and 100% duty cycle. (although ussually in reality it is limited to 5..95, IC and uC dependent). The block is called PWM Generator (DC-DC). There you just choose the requency and send an input in between 0 and 1. If you want to make it yourself use a repeating sequence with time values [0 1/fs] output [0 1], this generates a sawtooth and then compare it with your 0 to 1 value. The output will be a PWM with given DC and frequency fs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not easy to explain the whole thing in a simple post like in here. First-off, power supply designers rarely speak about PID coefficients but talk about poles and zeros placement. There are bridges between the two but as a power designer, I am more at ease to place a compensation zero than tweaking a D coefficient : ) Second, before attempting to stabilize anything, you need to characterize the dynamic response of your power stage (a voltage-mode buck-boost converter in your case). This is truly the starting point. That is, what transfer function \$H(s)\$ links my output variable (\$V_{out}\$ or \$I_{out}\$) to my control variable? This is expressed as \$H(s)=\frac{V_{out}(s)}{V_{err}(s)}\$ in which \$V_{err}(s)\$ is the voltage delivered by the compensation block (an op amp or your PID output whose transfer function is designated as \$G(s)\$). By adjusting \$V_{err}(s)\$ you have a means to adjust the output variable. However, as you control your series MOSFET through a duty ratio \$D\$ which is defined as \$D=\frac{t_{on}}{T_{sw}}\$, you need another block to convert the error voltage into a duty ratio. That block is called a pulse width modulator (PWM) and is shown below

[image]

This is what is called a naturally-sampled modulator and considering a perfect comparator its small-signal gain is simply \$\frac{1}{V_p}\$. It works by comparing the dc voltage \$V_{err}\$ with a ramp (whose peak amplitude is \$V_p\$) and when both meet, the comparator toggles. By changing \$V_{err}\$ you change \$D\$. I believe you may find a block like this in Simulink (https://fr.mathworks.com/help/slcontrol/ug/models-with-pulse-width-modulation-pwm-signals.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com).

You can obtain your power stage transfer function in many ways: analytical analysis, simulation with average models, bench experiments etc. but you need it before attempting to do anything. When you have it, you select a crossover frequency and calculate the pole-zero placement (or the PID coefficients) in the compensation block \$G(s)\$ to shape the loop gain \$H(s)G(s)\$ and build the desired phase and gain margins. That sounds complicated but it's not : )

Please have a look at a seminar I taught at APEC a while ago which describes the link between PID and poles/zeros and gives a lot of compensation examples: http://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202012.pdf. You will also find numerous other seminars on small-signal analysis and power stage characterization here http://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Spice.htm. Good luck with your circuit!

Comment: thank you so much! my circuit has come to life finally :)

Comment: I am glad to read this and happy if I could modestly help!

Answer (score 1):

In general, you need to use an ADC (analog to digital converter) channel on your Pi to monitor either voltage or current. From this measurement you adjust your pulse width modulation until the ADC value meets your required set point.

You do have issues with your schematic, however. Your FET is performing "high side" switching which makes the drive requirements a little more complicated. You will not be able to directly connect the Pi to the gate of the FET.

Your resistor on the right side of the diagram has only a connection to ground and the other end is not connected to the circuit.

Your ammeter and volt meter will not measure anything the way the circuit is configured.

You are not showing any component, voltage, or current values so analyzing the performance of the design is not possible.

I would suggest that you study some buck/boost converter designs available through many datasheets to get a better handle on how a typical circuit should work.

Comment: the converter works fine,the resistor is connected to the circuit via an ammeter, I have rearranged the the wires to make the circuit clearer and shown load voltage and current for 10% duty cycle.

Comment: Now that you have cleaned up your circuit, what question remains?

Comment: I wanna use a PI controller to control the duty cycle which will produce my desired load current, I have theoretical knowledge of PID controllers from college but don't know how to implement them in simulink or in real life

Comment: @HarshvirSingh The next step would be to modify the duty cycle of your pulse generator connected to the FET and observe the effect on the load. First try it with more on time and then with less on time and observe the effect on the load. In most simulators, you can modify the duty cycle by accessing the parameters of the generator block. Note that the change in output voltage comes as a result of changing the duty cycle (the ratio of on to off time) not the amplitude of the square wave.

Comment: I understand how the change in duty cycle will change the output voltage and current(if the duty cycle is less than 0.5 it performs as buck, else boost), to be very precise what I really want to do is to enter my required current somewhere in the circuit and the controller should produce a duty cycle for the FET that will provide that desired current and referring to the second picture, I really am getting the current equal to the amplitude I set for the signal generator

Comment: Isn't that what I explained in the first paragraph of my answer?

Comment: yes you did, sorry but could you please be more elaborate on that like shoukd I be using a feedback loop, what would be my adc input and output and controller input and output and where will the final duty cycle come from, sorry again for bothering so much